# error while hashing password using bcrypt in NodeJs and Typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, hash, bcrypt

I need help with my codes. I have successfully sent the hashed password to the database, but the login/authentication part where the "compare" is done isn't working. Its mostly saying password is undefined.

Here is the logic.

```
const salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync(10);

let tohash;

function hashPass(password) {
    tohash = bcrypt.hashSync(password, salt, function (err, hash) {
        if (err) return err;
        user.password = hash;

    });
    console.log('Password is ' + password);
    console.log('Tohash is ' + tohash);

    return { tohash: tohash };
}


function correctpass(password, user) {
    console.log('Tohash here is ' + tohash);

    let deHash = bcrypt.compare(password, user.password, function (err, result) {
        console.log('Password is ' + password);
        if (err) {
            console.log('Incorrect password');
        }
        console.log('Correct Password');
        return result;
    }); 

    return { deHash: deHash };
}


export { hashPass };
export { correctpass };
```

Here is where the invocation is done using Sequelize

const unHash = correctpass(password);
    try {

```
    user.findOne({
        where: {
            id : 55,
            email: "preciousegunjobi05@yahoo.com",
            //password: isPasswordCorrect.password.toString(),
            password: unHash.deHash(req.body.password),
            user_type: "tutor"
        }
    }).then(userdetails => {
        res.send(userdetails);
                console.log("data is " + userdetails);
```

Comment: Can you show some code?

Comment: Hi Anand, I have edited my question. The code is now there. thanks a lot

Comment: Can you tell us where the error is being thrown, can you add logs of those errors?

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'password' of undefined
    at Object.authentify (C:\Users\Razaq\Documents\Precious RNC\Tutoring Website\restInTypeORM\bizlogic\authentify.js:334:50)

Comment: There is another part of the code, where the invocation is done using sequelize.